# Patchbay Advice

Tags: patchbay

Not interested in switchcraft or bittree (nice but out of budget)

Looking for soem advice and suggestions on lower end market bays - specifically from those with experience with them.

Thinking the behringer model is nice, switchable on top for normalling options and 1/4 trs standard cables throughout.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I say Neutrik
http://www.neutrik.com/en/products/audio/patch-panels/1/4-patch-panel/nys-spp-l1

They are a leaders in the industry of connectors and this model is really cheap, I like mine, surely it is better then behringer,

Answer (score 0):

We use Signex entry-level patchbays (QPP48), but we have never had a problem with them.  We don't use then day-in-day-out, but have been using them fairly regularly for four years now.

Answer (score 0):

You could also go for a Redco. They have DB25 connectors on the back, are Bantam (not TRS) and quite solidly built. Also, Redco can custom make almost any cable for you, very moderately priced.

http://www.redco.com/Redco-R196-D25PG.html